# Gnome - Determine keyboard layout

Tags: linux, keyboard, gnome

I was wondering how it might be possible to determine the currently used keyboard layout in a gnome session, when the user switches keyboard layouts via an applet. As of now I do not care, what programming language or libraries (gtk,x,...) I have to use for it.

I asked a similar question before on: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/155879/how-to-get-current-gnome-keyboard-layout-from-terminal

Unfortunatelly nobody could solve the issue, which is why I wanted to ask you. How do you determine the current keyboard layout in your programms/scripts.

Thanks

ftiaronsem

Answer (score 1):

On the command line or from within scripts you can use setxkbmap:

```
$ setxkbmap -print | awk -F"+" '/xkb_symbols/ {print $2}'
gb
```

Or the -query option:

```
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     gb
```

Comment: Hm. Without GUI I cannot view this part. It gives me `Cannot open display "default display"`.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard layout is stored in the settings of X. (/etc/X11/xorg.conf)

Personally I would try parsing that file (or find a parser for it) and try to determine the layout that way.

Since I am not that experienced with X11, I do not know whether there might even be an API to query these settings.

I must say that I do not know whether that is the only place where it can be configured. Someone else might be able to confirm that.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunatelly, the /etc/X11/xorg.conf only holds the keyboard definitions. Of course one can set a default keyboard layout there, but the gnome session settings take precedence over it.

Comment: @ftiaronsem, I think your question is more a matter of "where is the keyboard layout config stored". Once you know where to find it, it should be easy to get it.

Comment: @Goeman: I agree, that would be a possibility. However I somehow fear that it is saved in some session variable in ram and only written to disk on shtudown/boot...

Comment: @ftiaronsem, that would be very strange. I can not imagine that you would lose such settings after a crash. Maybe you can check the code of the applet that does the switch? Maybe I will also have a look when I have time.